# loading multiple data in a delimited text file

Tags: qgis

I am trying to map out a pipeline, identifying where the pipeline is covered by more than 0.6m of sediment and where the pipeline is not covered by 0.6m of sediment. I have gathered this information in excel and saved it as a *csv. file*. (seen below) I also have the same excel sheet expressing DOC (depth of coverage) being greater than 0.6m.

[image]

Note, I have got over 1000 data points all with a specified easting and northing. Using QGIS I `add layer` --> `Add Delimited Text Layer` and upload the document (Shown below).

[image]

When I add the layer, It doesn't show on my map even when I right click the layer and `zoom to layer`.

What I am trying to achieve is to plot all 1000 data points according to their Easting's and Northing (in a line), where I can change them from *point data* to *line data* then I can add *rules to it* so I can identify where the areas lower than 0.6m are and where they are greater than 0.6m. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Comment: Based on your screenshot you cannot see your features because you have chosen a geographic coordinate system, but your coordinates in your file are projected. You need to change the 'Geometry CRS' dropdown to whatever projected coordinate system your data is in.

Comment: Perfect and thankyou. Changed the CRS from WGS84 to ED50 and it works a treat

Comment: @pdavis please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your screenshot you cannot see your features because you have chosen a geographic coordinate system, but your coordinates in your file are projected. You need to change the 'Geometry CRS' dropdown to whatever projected coordinate system your data is in.

As for your last 2 questions, those are likely candidates for separate questions after you can articulate what you've tried and what is not working.